# Dired+ hangs emacs in -no window mode

Tags: init-file, package, dired, use-package

I have this in my init.el file:

```
(use-package dired
  :init
  (progn
    ;; Details toggling is bound to "(" in `dired-mode' by default
    (setq diredp-hide-details-initially-flag nil))  
  :config
  (use-package dired+
    :ensure t)
  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'auto-revert-mode)
  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook  (lambda () (setq auto-revert-verbose nil)))
  )
```

Running Emacs with no window mode `emacs -nw` and when moving cursors I get "change ownership" instead when in directory view.
Removing the code related to Dired+ solved the problem.
Any pointers to why that happens? If no workaround, is there a way to disable Dired+ mode only when running `emacs -nw`

Comment: 1. I can't repro the problem from a virgin Emacs. Could you please try to repro the problem using `emacs -nw -Q` and explicitly requiring `dired+.el` (i.e., not using `use-package`), and send it along to me by email (see file header).

Comment: 2. I don't know about `use-package`, but if you explicitly put `dired+.el` in your `load-path` and then put `(require 'dired+)` in your init file, you can make the latter conditional: `(when (display-graphic-p) (require 'dired+.el))` will require it only when Emacs is not in terminal mode.

Comment: 1. (continued) Also, please describe when the hang occurs. Does it occur when a revert occurs? When Dired mode is set up (a directory is visited)? When?

Comment: This worked for me (when (display-graphic-p) (use-package dired+ :ensure t)). Drew, if I don't specify a file to open, I have it setup to open in dired mode, so it hangs directly. No reverting or anything, I can't move the cursor. I have not tried with (require) since all my init file is setup using use-package. Will see if I can perform the experiment.

Comment: The first thing to try is to see if you see the same problem without Dired+, i.e., with vanilla `dired.el` plus `dired-x.el` plus `dired-aux.el` (those are loaded by Dired+). I assume that you already tried that and determined that the problem is with Dired+. But if you didn't then please do that first.

Comment: I still see the problem when starting with vanilla emacs and only (require 'dired+) in init.el. There is no issue when requiring all three other files (dired, dired-x, dired-aux). I also found that it is not an actual hang, but cursor not moving with arrows and hitting enter will ask to change owner of the file at point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dired+ is binding shortcuts that conflict with the character sequences that your terminal is sending when you hit the arrow keys.  Something very similar happened to me.  Here is how I handled it:

```
(use package dired+ :config
    (define-key dired-mode-map [(meta shift ?o)] nil))
```

When I pressed an arrow key, dired+'s key-binding for `'diredp-chmod-this-file` was erroneously triggered, until I unbound it like above.  This happened for me in both linux and Mac OS X terminal emulators, but I'm not sure if your terminal emulator is sending the exact same sequence; if not, you'll have to adjust the above.  To see what a character sequence really is, press `Control-h c` and then, say, an arrow key, to have emacs print out what key it is receiving based upon that character sequence.

Comment: Yup, this same setup solved the problem.

Comment: Great. The missing info came from the OP's last comment - about what action (pressing cursor keys) led to the problem. OP: Please put that info in the question, so it is complete. (Comments can be deleted at any time.) Thx.

Comment: Issue updated. Thanks Drew.

Comment: See also this node in the Org manual: `(info "(org) TTY keys")` - same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the info from this question and the answer by @InHarmsWay, I've updated [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) to add this user option, whose value defaults to `t`:

> **`diredp-bind-problematic-terminal-keys`** is a variable defined in [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means bind some keys that might not work in terminal mode.
>
> This applies to keys that use modifiers Meta and Shift together.
>   If you use Emacs in terminal mode (`emacs -nw`) and your terminal does
>   not support the use of such keys then customize this option to `nil`.

The problematic keys (for some terminals) are these:

```
`M-M'       (aka `M-S-m')       - `diredp-chmod-this-file'
`M-O'       (aka `M-S-o')       - `diredp-chown-this-file'
`M-T'       (aka `M-S-t')       - `diredp-touch-this-file'
`C-M-B'     (aka `C-M-S-b')     - `diredp-do-bookmark-in-bookmark-file'
`C-M-G'     (aka `C-M-S-g')     - `diredp-chgrp-this-file'
`C-M-R'     (aka `C-M-S-r')     - `diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir'
`C-M-T'     (aka `C-M-S-t')     - `dired-do-touch'
`M-+ M-B'   (aka `M-+ M-S-b')   - `diredp-do-bookmark-dirs-recursive'
`M-+ C-M-B' (aka `M-+ C-M-S-b') - `diredp-do-bookmark-in-bookmark-file-recursive'
`M-+ C-M-T' (aka `M-+ C-M-S-t') - `diredp-do-touch-recursive'
```

Comment: Thanks Drew. I checked list-packages but there is no update yet for Dired+, when is the update is expected to show up?

Comment: It is here now (I always upload to Emacs Wiki): https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el. It is then mirrored on MELPA up to a day later.

Comment: Drew, not sure how to apply this. I have added this setq : (setq diredp-bind-problematic-terminal-keys nil) but I keep getting the change owner when moving the cursor. I changed it's value to t and I still get same issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: Update: ok seems like I applied it at the wrong time in my use-package. Should be in init and not config block.